# DOD STIG fix for Java Security Manager not working

Tags: java, security, tomcat, stig

I'm trying to apply a DOD STIG fix for Java Security Manager. The fix requires me to modify the */etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service* file and set the "ExecStart" parameter to read:
`ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh -security`.

After I applied this fix, tomcat would fail to start. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

I added `-security` to the end of `ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`. After saving/exiting the tomcat.service file, I applied the `systemctl daemon-reload` command. I'm expecting tomcat to run as expected but it fails to start after a while.

When I restarted tomcat, catalina.out showed the following:

> 19-Oct-2023 14:16:26.412 SEVERE [acop-startStop-1]
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container
> failed during start
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[a2].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/a2]]
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:892)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:793)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1362)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1352)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[a2].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/a2]]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
> ... 6 more
> Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission"
> "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.connector")
> at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
> at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:886)
> at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
> at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1564)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.run(ClassLoader.java:496)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.run(ClassLoader.java:494)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkPackageAccess(ClassLoader.java:494)
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection$1.run(Introspection.java:106)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection$1.run(Introspection.java:103)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:102)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:329)

Comment: what happens if you attempt to start manually on the commandline `./startup.sh -security` ?

Comment: and after committing the change, before running `systemctl daemon-reload` did you restart Tomcat: `sudo systemctl restart tomcat` ?

Comment: @MadsHansen I forgot to mention that. I certainly input systemctl restart tomcat before using systemctl daemon-reload. When I tried to use ./startup.sh manually, it failed to start.

Comment: And nothing logged or spit out to indicate that there is an issue?

Comment: Edit your question and put these details there.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [modify your `conf/catalina.policy`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Configuring_Tomcat_With_A_SecurityManager) and include some additional permissions, such as:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.connector";
```

Comment: that permission was denied too.